# Can't use my galaxy w instead of the emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I had been using my phone instead of the emulator until I bought my new Windows 8 Laptop. But it is not working. I tried to install Samsung Kies, re-install, install older version (2.3.2), tried to follow the processes from the very beginning by searching how to use it. But none of them work.

I am tring for several days, Usb debugging is enabled, I tried to re-connect phone, re-start windows.

I can see my phone on DDMS but I cant see on Virtual device maneger.

Comment: which IDE you using and Is your phone charging when you connect it to the PC via USB??

Comment: Yeah it is charging and I menage my files if I connect as a storage

Comment: ok good now tell me are you using eclipse or something else

Comment: Have you tried to restart Eclipse, Windows and the phone? Disconnect and re-connect the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

1. Check if your computer had your phone driver. I assume that your use `Windows`. Open `Device Manager`

   - At a command prompt, in the Start Search box, or in the Run box, type the following          command: `mmc devmgmt.msc`
   - . Other ways : check [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754221%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

   If you find your phone name or `ADB Interface` so you got driver. Try to restart `DDMS` or restart your `Eclipse`.

   1. If you don't find your device or see something `Other device with yellow question mark` so try to install driver by browsing on your phone to `Settings` - `Developer Options` - `Enable developer option` - `Enable USB debugging` - `Plug your phone to computer`. Windows will ask you to install driver.

3, Update Google USB driver in Android SDK Manager (in Eclipse) or search `Samsung Galaxy W driver`

4.Some weird case i got on some device.

- Nexus S: disable Developer option. Restart phone. Enable again. Windows ask to install driver or you will see it in `Eclipse`.
- HTC phone or Samsung : change `Connectivity Option` on phone to `Charge only` (Swipe status bar. Check notifications displayed). Some phone set it to some kind of **Sync data** so Windows can not recognize device.

Comment: I can see my phone on DDMS And it says Online

Comment: ok then uncheck the usb debugging and restart your phone. Uncheck first and then restart the phone

Comment: I unchaked it, restarted the phone, chacked the usb debugging, connected to PC. I can still see on DDMs as online but I cant see it on Virtual Device Manager.

Comment: It works know, I tried I lot of thing I am not sure what was the problem :) but it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Enable developer option from settings on your phone and if you are using eclipse. You don't to worry about anything else . And please give the IDE you are using .

Verify if you have installed the usb kit from the on sdk.developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html  .

Comment: how can I enable developer option? if you mean usb debugging it is enabled I am using Eclipse,

Comment: Verify if you have installed the usb kit from the on sdk.http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: it is installed latest version

Answer (score 0):

enable usb debugging from your device and install  [Samsung USB driver](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/SAMSUNG-USB-Driver-for-Mobile-Phones-15150.shtml) that will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I used eclipse to develop for Android. I enable USB debugging in Settings/Applications/Development, connect it to my machine, and it shows up in eclipse as target device to run the project on.

What are the symptoms you have? Any error message? How do you try to run the application?

Comment: the problem is I cant see is as target device in eclipse, no error I cant just not see it